# Python and Mysql quotes and variables

Tags: python, mysql

I've run in to a problem i don't know how to solve.

I have this line:

```
parse = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE Match(name) AGAINST         ('"The.New.York.Times"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);")
```

If I run:

```
parse = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE Match(name) AGAINST ('"The.New.York.Times"'     IN BOOLEAN MODE);")
```

in mysql console, it works. But I guess python doesn't like the `'"The.New.York.Times"'` the quotes. How do I solve that?

And also, how would i in python make that search string a variable? 
Something along the lines of

```
parse = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE Match(name) AGAINST ('"%s"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);, var1")
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid sql injections and get proper escaping, you should pass query variables as a second parameter to `execute`:

```
param = '"The.New.York.Times"'
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM predb WHERE Match(name) AGAINST (%s IN BOOLEAN MODE)", (param, ))
```

Comment: That code did not work, however if i removed the '' from %s it did work, thanks for the help!!

Comment: Ok, great. I thought you needed '"' there.

Comment: Generally, you don't need the semi-colon at the end of the statement. It's also worth reading the [Python DB API FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq). (Which paramtype is supported may depend on the DB driver.)